# Is there any API available for creating a route account in razorpay?

Tags: loopbackjs, razorpay

I'm using loopback 3.x ,I wanted to create a route account in **Razorpay**. Is there any builtin API is available for that? Also I required the corresponding account id for a particular user. Is that possible with loopback? If yes, how to integrate it with loopback?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: No, I didn't get. @harshitverma